# PHP substr giving weird characters from xml feed

Tags: php, xml

For some reason when using substr I am getting a weird character on output like this "".

All I am doing is this:

```
$price = substr($game->price, 1);
$dollars_original = substr($game->fullPrice, 1);
echo "Price: $" . $price . "<br />\n";
echo "Original Price: $" . $dollars_original . "<br />\n";
```

This comes from an XML feed here: http://itch.io/browse/platform-linux/price-sale.xml which i parse like so:

```
$url = 'http://itch.io/browse/platform-linux/price-sale.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($url));
```

So for example a price might be £0.89 but, when removing the £ sign it comes out as �0.89

What am I missing here?

Comment: Verify that the output encoding matches the input encoding. � is a placeholder token for non existing characters.

Comment: That symbol is actually for an _invalid_ (improperly formed) UTF-8 multibyte character. Usually it means a Latin-1/Windows-1252 single byte character from the range x80-xFF, or a UTF-8 multibyte character got cut in two.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a mixup in character encodings. What is Latin-1 or Windows-1252, and what is UTF-8? If you're working on UTF-8 data, you may have to use mb_substr(), which is UTF-8 aware.